# Enable apcu on php 7.3 Mac OS Mojave

Tags: php, apc

On PHP 7.3.6

I have installed apcu by brew.

It looks installed successfully on both browser and CLI

```
$ php -m | grep apc
apcu
```

php info on browser

```
apcu
APCu Support    Enabled
Version 5.1.17
APCu Debugging  Disabled
MMAP Support    Enabled
MMAP File Mask  no value
Serialization Support   php
Build Date  Jul 1 2019 12:34:19
```

However,Both code below shows the wrror.

`\apc_exists("test");`

`apc_exists("test");`

```
Attempted to call function 'apc_exists' from the global namespace. (500 Internal Server Error)
```

Is there any other place I need to check??

Comment: Have you installed apcu_bc (backward compatibility) as well? You need it for sure!

Comment: It works well and help me!! thanks you very much